# Be notified when a user tweets, using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am playing around with a twitter bot using tweepy.

I have got the code to successfully filter, based on words contained in the tweets (e.g. my trigger phrase), doing something like:

```
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=MyStreamListener())
myStream.filter(track=['my trigger phrase'])
```

This works perfectly.

But I want my code to filter when a certain user tweets (e.g. 'someuser').

I had tried:

```
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=MyStreamListener())
myStream.filter(follow=['someuser'])
```

But when I run the code, after a second or two, it stops with no output.

Any help would be great.

In summary, I want to be able to do something whenever a certain user tweets.

---

The entire code:

```
import tweepy
import time
import sys
import inspect

consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
auth.secure = True

api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
            if  status.user.screen_name.encode('UTF-8').lower() == 'someuser':
                print 'TWEET:', status.text.encode('UTF-8')
                print 'FOLLOWERS:', status.user.followers_count
                print time.ctime()
                print '\n'

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=MyStreamListener())
myStream.filter(follow=['someuser'])
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `MyStreamListener`?

Comment: Apologies. Have now posted everything above.

Comment: Try removing the `if` statement from your `on_status` method. The `filter` method should take care of only returning the correct tweets.

Comment: When I get rid of the if statement, the same thing happens - the code runs for a few seconds and then stop. No error message, I just get back to my terminal prompt.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be the last line that's the problem. When I change "follow" to "track" then it works. But I believe this just helps you track if a work is in the tweet. Perhaps follow is not the right thing to have used.

Comment: *helps you track if a word...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was just that I was trying to enter:

follow=['someuser']

But I needed to be using the user id number and not just the screen name.

You can find the user id number for any screen name on various web sites.

Answer (score 4):

I use this for retrive the Id_user for follow in Stream

```
auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = API(auth) 
user = api.get_user(screen_name = '@screenametofollow')
print ("User id:" + str(user.id))
....
stream.filter(follow=str(user.id))
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Newbie, i edit my message with only the answer, without question.